# Spark Streaming to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am accessing the data from Apache Kafka through Apache Spark Streaming so I want to store the Data in the `MongoDB`   so How Can i store it in `mongoDB` ?

Comment: Did you try [google](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/03/20/using-mongodb-with-spark.html)?

Answer (score 1):

The output operations are quite limited, but you can always use `foreachRDD()` where you have access to any processed RDD in this timeframe. So any custom logic can be placed here, i.e. having a connection to MongoDB perform a simple insert/update operation explicitly.